# show $((p \to q) \land (r \to s) \land (p \lor r )) \to (q \lor s)$ is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have tried the following but then got stuck:

I apply the implication rule to the first two elements:

$((\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r)) \to (q \lor s)$

Then again to the entire equation:

$\lnot((\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r)) \lor (q \lor s)$

I am not sure how to distribute the negation sign.

Comment: De Morgan's properly in which line? You seem to have forgotten to change the "or" to an "and" sign (and vice versa) when negating.

Comment: sorry, which line are you referring to?

Comment: All of them, really.

Comment: It's better if you show what you did so that someone can point out the error.  Otherwise, you're just asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Have you tried proving it via truth tables? That is generally the quickest way, since there's less (albeit any) guesswork.

Comment: @MJD great, yup. am working on it now.

Comment: @Inazuma, will try that straight after.

Comment: De Morgan's rule is not the rule that says that $p\to q$ is equivalent to $\sim p \lor q$.  It is the rule that says that $\sim(p\land q)$ is equivalent to $\sim p\lor\sim q$.  You need to use De Morgan's rule.

Comment: @MJD does that apply to when there's more than two elements?

Comment: ah ok, I think I see the mistake now.

Answer (score 1):

De Morgan's Laws:

$\lnot (p \lor q) = \lnot p \land \lnot q$ (note that the "or" sign changes into "and")

$\lnot (p \land q) = \lnot p \lor \lnot q$ (note that the "and" sign changes into "or")

This is because the negation of "and" is "or" and vice versa.

So from your situation:

\begin{align}
&\lnot((\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r)) \lor (q \lor s)
\\
\equiv\,& (p \land \lnot q) \lor (r \land \lnot s) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot r) \lor (q \lor s)
\end{align}

From here you can expand everything out, use some associative properties, and voila!

Answer (score 1):

Since we have $p \vee r$, we have at least one of $p$ or $r$.

- If we have $p$, then since we have $p \to q$, we have $q$; so we certainly have $q \vee s$.
- If we have $r$, then since we have $r \to s$, we have $s$; so we certainly have $q \vee s$.